# Elasticsearch complex proximity query

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, proximity

Given that I have a query like below:

`council* W/5 (tip OR tips)`

The above query can be translated as: Find anything that has **council***  and **(tip OR tips)** no more than 5 words apart.

So following text will match:

- Shellharbour City **Council Tip**
- **council** best **tip**
- **councils** top 10 **tips**

But this one should not match:

- ... City **Council** at Shellharbour. There is not any good **tip** at all.

I need help to build an elasticsearch query for that. I was thinking about Regex query but I'm not quite sure about better alternatives. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [span_near](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) query, [span_multi](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-multi-term-query.html) and [span_or](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-or-query.html). We can use the query below to perform the same search.

```
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_multi":
          {
            "match":
            {
              "prefix": { "text": "council"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "span_or": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "text": {
                    "value": "tip"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "text": {
                    "value": "tips"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop": 5,
      "in_order": true
    }
  }
}
```

The important things to look out for are the **span_term** which is the text your searching for. In this example I only had one field called "text". **Slop** indicates the number of words we will allow between the terms, and **in_order** indicates that the order of words is important. So "tip council" will not match, where as "council tip" will.

Comment: Thank mate, that's exactly what I'm looking for. My queries are very complicated, I'll have to implement something to translate those queries using these span_* elasticsearch query.